# Shell script: How to delete all files in a directory except ones listed in a file?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory (`~/temp/`) that contains many files and sub directories, and in some directories, they may contain other files and sub directories. 
Also, in the directory (`~/temp/`), it contains a special txt file with name `kept.txt`, it list some direct files and sub directories that contained in `~/temp/`, now i want to delete all other files and directories under `~/temp/` that are not listed in the `kept.txt` file, how to do this with a shell command, the simpler the better.

e.g.

The directory likes as below:

```
$ tree temp/ -F
temp/
 ├── a/
 ├── b/
 ├── c/
 │   ├── f2.txt
 │   └── z/
 ├── f1.txt
 └── kept.txt
```

The content of `kept.txt` is:

```
$ more kept.txt
b
kept.txt
```

For this case:

1. i want to delete `a/`, `c/` and `f1.txt`. For `c/`, the directory itself and all sub content (files and directories) will be deleted.
2. In `kept.txt`, the format is one item (file or directory) per line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `extglob` you can do this:

```
cd temp
shopt -s extglob

rm -rf !($(printf "%s|" $(<kept.txt)))
```

`printf "%s|" $(<kept.txt)` will provide output as `b|kept.txt|` and `!(...)` is an [extended glob pattern](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) to negate the match.

Comment: Except that will delete `kept.txt` as well.

Comment: No it will not delete that because OP has `kept.txt` line in file `kept.txt` as well.

Comment: @anubhava Cool! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Move everything to a temporary folder. Move back the files/directories listed in the .txt. Then, last, remove the temporary folder.

Comment: Yes, this is a simple good way to solve this issue, but i'm not sure if there is some simple command to do this.